# How do you ensure your MVC routes don't conflict with each other? What tracking system do you use?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

What system do you use to ensure that changes to the MVC route table does not cause conflicts, or hidden routes?

Please share details.  For example, if in Excel, how do you organize it?

I am not interested in the technical manner in which the routes are applied to the website (attributes, global.asax, etc) unless your technical solution also directly relates to an at-a-glance route management system.

Comment: This might help you: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally [unit test my routes](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TestHelper#Routes) and a in order to ensure that changes to my routes table doesn't cause conflicts I run my unit tests and look for the Red color.

Answer (score 1):

Routing in MVC is hard and error prone, that's why I created the **[MvcCodeRouting](http://mvccoderouting.codeplex.com/)** library. Among other things it detects conflicts (you'll get an exception) and you can also see the routes it creates for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Use unit tests, and to reduce number of them you can make data driven tests.